# Can I import `__version__` in the top-level `__init__.py` from a sub-package without a circular import error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, circular-dependency, python-packaging

I'm developing a GUI app as a Python package and have an issue. If I install the package in editable mode with `pip install -e .`, then it works fine, but if I try to just `pip install` it normally, then when I run it, I get a circular import error.

My (simplified) project structure looks like this:

```
package/
  __init__.py
  __main__.py
  gui/
    main_window.py
    dialogs/
      misc.py
  typing_/
    __init__.py
```

`package/typing_/__init__.py` contains type aliases which are used all over the codebase. Many files have `from package.typing_ import AliasName` without issue, although this may be because these imports come last, so the package fails to import before reaching them.

The main circular import error comes from `package/gui/dialogs/misc.py`, which contains an `AboutDialog` class. This class wants `package.__version__`, which is defined in `package/__init__.py`, to display the version in the about box.

I've tried `import package` and using `package.__version__`, as well as `from package import __version__`, but neither of them work and both result in a circular import error.

It's not crucial to the development, because the package still works in editable mode, but there's clearly some bad design going on and I want to fix it.

Comment: does `package/__init__.py` also import something from `gui.dialogs.misc` ?

Comment: Perhaps just move the version number to a separate `_version.py` module, which both `package/__init__.py` and `package/guit/dialogs/misc.py` import.

Comment: @Anentropic `package/__init__.py` only has `from . import gui, matrices, typing_`, the `__version__`, and `__all__`, which exports these 4 things.